# What to do if PhoneGap Build fails without error message?

Tags: android, phonegap-build, cordova-plugin-proguard

Using PhoneGap Build to build an cordova application. It's started to fail building without any explanation. Their forum isn't the greatest so I thought I'd post on here in case it's happening to other people and is an issue that needs more visibility. If anyone has any advice on how to resolve I would be very grateful. Here's the output from the log:

```
Build Date: 2018-07-17 13:27:05 +0000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PREPARE OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for android at /res/xml/config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific android config.xml
Merging and updating files from [, ../platform_www] to ../assets/www
  copy  app.css ../assets/www/app.css (new file)
  copy  app.css.map ../assets/www/app.css.map (new file)
  copy  app.js ../assets/www/app.js (new file)
  copy  app.js.map ../assets/www/app.js.map (new file)
  mkdir ../assets/www/audio
  mkdir ../assets/www/audio/bright
  ...[Skiping for brevity]
  copy  res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png ../res/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.png (new file)
  copy  res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png ../res/drawable-port/screen.png (new file)
This app does not have additional resource files defined
Prepared android project successfully
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PLUGIN OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-camera@~2.3.1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-camera" at "2.3.1" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-compat@^1.1.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" at "1.2.0" for android
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 6.3.0, failed version requirement: 
      <6.3.0
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-compat' for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-device@1.1.2" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" at "1.1.2" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-geolocation@2.4.3" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-geolocation" at "2.4.3" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-compat@1.2.0" already fetched, using that version.
Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" at "1.2.0" for android
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 6.3.0, failed version requirement: 
      <6.3.0
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-compat' for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@1.3.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" at "1.3.0" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-network-information@1.2.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-network-information" at "1.2.0" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-vibration@2.1.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-vibration" at "2.1.0" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-media@2.2.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-media" at "2.2.0" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-file@^4.0.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-file" at "4.3.3" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-compat@1.2.0" already fetched, using that version.
Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" at "1.2.0" for android
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 6.3.0, failed version requirement: 
      <6.3.0
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-compat' for android

The Android Persistent storage location now defaults to "Internal". Please check this plugin's README to see if your application needs any changes in its config.xml.

If this is a new application no changes are required.

If this is an update to an existing application that did not specify an "AndroidPersistentFileLocation" you may need to add:

      "<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />"

to config.xml in order for the application to find previously stored files.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.2.1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" at "1.2.1" for android

               This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation@v1.4.1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" at "1.4.0" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-splashscreen@3.2.2" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" at "3.2.2" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.1.3" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-statusbar" at "2.1.3" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-file-transfer@1.6.3" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" at "1.6.3" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file@4.3.3" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on android.
Plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on android. Making it top-level.
Fetching plugin "cordova-sqlite-storage@0.8.5" via npm
Installing "cordova-sqlite-storage" at "0.8.5" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-code-push@1.11.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-code-push" at "1.11.0" for android
Fetching plugin "code-push@2.0.4" via npm
Installing "code-push" at "2.0.4" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file-transfer@1.6.3" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file-transfer" already installed on android.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-zip@>=3.0.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-zip" at "3.1.0" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file@4.3.3" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on android.
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-dialogs@>=1.1.1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-dialogs" at "2.0.1" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-device@1.1.2" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-device" already installed on android.
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Fetching plugin "ionic-plugin-keyboard@v2.2.0" via npm
Installing "ionic-plugin-keyboard" at "2.2.0" for android
Fetching plugin "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner@5.0.0" via npm
Installing "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" at "5.0.0" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-compat@1.2.0" already fetched, using that version.
Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" at "1.2.0" for android
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 6.3.0, failed version requirement: 
      <6.3.0
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-compat' for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Fetching plugin "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator@3.1.1" via npm
Installing "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" at "3.1.1" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-actionsheet@^2.2.2" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-actionsheet" at "2.3.3" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-email@1.1.1" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-email" at "1.1.1" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-appavailability@^0.4.2" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-appavailability" at "0.4.2" for android
Fetching plugin "https://github.com/xmartlabs/cordova-plugin-market" via git clone
Using shallow clone
Repository "https://github.com/xmartlabs/cordova-plugin-market" checked out to git ref "master" at "44b058a".
Installing "cordova-plugin-market" at "1.2.0" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing@^5.1.8" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" at "5.4.1" for android
Fetching plugin "es6-promise-plugin@^4.1.0" via npm
Installing "es6-promise-plugin" at "4.2.2" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview@^2.3.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" at "2.4.0" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib

        After much discussion and analysis of the market, we have decided to discontinue support for Android 4.0 (ICS) in Crosswalk starting with version 20.

        So the minSdkVersion of Cordova project is configured to 16 by default.
Fetching plugin "cordova-android-support-gradle-release@^1.2.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-android-support-gradle-release" at "1.4.4" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller@1.5.3" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller" at "1.5.3" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme@^4.3.0" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" at "4.3.0" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-appcenter-analytics@^0.1.5" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-appcenter-analytics" at "0.1.6" for android
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-appcenter-shared@0.1.6" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-appcenter-shared" at "0.1.6" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-appcenter-crashes@^0.1.5" via npm
Installing "cordova-plugin-appcenter-crashes" at "0.1.6" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-appcenter-shared@0.1.6" already fetched, using that version.
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-appcenter-shared" already installed on android.
Subproject Path: CordovaLib

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PROJECT PROPERTIES
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
# Project target.
target=android-26
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-code-push/zaptic-build-extras.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/zaptic-barcodescanner.gradle
cordova.system.library.2=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3+
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/zaptic-xwalk.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.4=cordova-android-support-gradle-release/zaptic-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.5=cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller/zaptic-SafariViewController-java18.gradle
cordova.system.library.4=com.android.support:customtabs:23.2.0
cordova.system.library.5=com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter:1.6.1
cordova.system.library.6=com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-analytics:1.6.1
cordova.system.library.7=com.microsoft.appcenter:appcenter-crashes:1.6.1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COMPILE OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here's the post of their community forum: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2514247

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out that downgrading cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller to 1.4.7 seem to fix the issue. I suspect it was the change to Java 1.8 (Java 8):

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller/pull/86/files